Wind Speed Definition of HERE Destination Weather
I am using the HERE Destination Weather API to get Wind Speed from a Weather observation. The documentation of this value is below, but it doesn't specify what wind speed definition is being used. The definition per NOAA is "2-minute average speed at 10 m height", but other meteorological such as MET seem to use a 10 minute average speed.
Is anyone able to shed some insight or details as to what definition Here is using for wind speed?

Wind speed in km/h or mph.
If the element is in the response and it contains a value, there is a Double in the String. If the element is in the response and it does not contain a value, there is an asterisk (*) in the String.
The value used depends on the metric parameter value.

